# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with this id = { "2"} of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

this is my code when i want tp update  my featureDisa entity i get this error
and i dont know why this happen. and there is one point is that i can not use AsNoTracking() beacuse i need log something

```
var updateFeatureDisas = await _featureDisaRepository.
                GetAll()
                 .Where(a => featureDisaIdInsert.Contains(a.DisadvantageId) &&
                 featureIdInsert.Contains(a.FeatureId)
                 && featureParentIdInsert.Contains(a.ParentFeatureId)).ToListAsync();
    
            var sqInsertFeatureDisa = insertTagDisa.Where(a => updateFeatureDisas.All(d => d.Id != a.Id)).ToList();
    
    
    
            if (updateFeatureDisas.Any())
            {
                var sqUpdateFeatureDisa = insertTagDisa.Where(a => updateFeatureDisas.
                    All(d => d.Id.Equals(a.Id, StringComparison.Ordinal))).ToList();
                var updateFeatureDisa = _mapper.Map<List<FeatureDisa>>(sqUpdateFeatureDisa);
                _featureDisaRepository.UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync(updateFeatureDisa);
            }
```

and this my UpdateWithOutSaveChangeAsync

```
public void UpdateWithOutSaveChangeAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    DbContext.Update(entity);
}
```

Comment: Mapping to a new List means that the entities in that mapped list aren't being tracked. Does `UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync` try to attach these entities before doing the update? Is the mapping actually necessary here?

Comment: Yse is necessary  beacuse the UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync update the my FeatureDisa table and get featureDisaEntity and i should pass featureDisa to this update method @Luke

Comment: Please edit your post to include the `UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync` method (please include the method signature as well)

Comment: I did it and now include UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync   @Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF change tracking works with references. When you load an entity from a DbContext, by default EF tracks that reference. If you later create another copy of an entity with the same ID and tell the DbContext to `Update` the row with it, EF first checks its tracking list and throws this error if it finds that it is already tracking another copy of the entity with the same ID.

So this code:

```
var updateFeatureDisa = _mapper.Map<List<FeatureDisa>>(sqUpdateFeatureDisa);
```

... is your problem. Automapper is constructing new FeatureDisa entity instances which you are trying to tell EF to Update rows, but you have already read and tracked entities.

Solution 1: Tell EF to not track references when loading the Features. If your Repository method is returning an `IQueryable` and you've done it properly where the query hasn't been materialized in the Repository then:

```
var updateFeatureDisas = await _featureDisaRepository.GetAll()
    .AsNoTracking() // <- Just add this...
    .Where(a => featureDisaIdInsert.Contains(a.DisadvantageId) 
        && featureIdInsert.Contains(a.FeatureId)
        && featureParentIdInsert.Contains(a.ParentFeatureId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

This ***should*** work, but there is a big caveat to be aware of. When dealing with injected DbContexts, this one statement will load the requested FeatureDisas without adding them to the tracking cache, but it may be possible that other code/calls within the lifetime scope of that DbContext (I.e. Request) might load and track one or more FeatureDisa entities. It is certainly a risk of an intermittent exception or breaking change if someone is not careful and aware of this dependency.

Option 1a: To ensure that the above code is "safe", we need to ensure that before calling "Update" the DbContext is not tracking any instance. If it is, tell it to Detach it. It would be nice to do this in your UpdateWithoutSaveChangesAsync method, but as a Generic method that won't work because we need to find any existing item in the tracking cache by ID.

```
public void UpdateWithOutSaveChangeAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    var existingEntity = DbContext.DbSet<TEntity>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id); // Doesn't work due to Generic implementation
    if (existingEntity != null)
        dbContext.Entry(existingEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    DbContext.Update(entity);
}
```

Unfortunately that code won't work because we cannot do that in a Generic unless we have a common base type to access the ID that we can possibly cast to.  So it will have to be done in the FeatureDisaRepository .UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync() method before it calls that Update:

Assuming UpdateRangeWithoutSaveChangeAsync is itself a Generic implementation: Something like:

```
 public async Task UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync(List<FeatureDisa> featureDisas)
 {
      var featureDisaIds = featureDisas.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
      var trackedFeatureDisas = DbContext.FeatureDisas.Local
           .Where(x => featureDisaIds.Contains(x.Id))
           .ToList();

      foreach(var trackedFeatureDisa in trackedFeatureDisas)
          DbContext.Entry(trackedFeatureDisa).State = EntityState.Detached;

      return base.UpdateRangeWithOutSaveChangeAsync(featureDisas); // hand off to the Generic method to do the work.
}
```

That's basically pulled from my head, depending on how your repository is implemented it's probably going to get more messy due to the Generic pattern. (I really do not recommend Generic Repositories /w EF for reasons like this)

Option 2: Fortunately there is a better option than all of that which Automapper can facilitate. Automapper can copy values between references, so leaving your original read call loading tracked references, instead of:

```
 var updateFeatureDisa = _mapper.Map<List<FeatureDisa>>(sqUpdateFeatureDisa);
```

Use automapper's copy mapping method call:

```
foreach(var updated in sqUpdateFeatureDisa)
{
    var existingFeatureDisa = updateFeatureDisas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = updated.Id);
    if (existingFeatureDisa == null) continue; // What else to do if we don't have a matching existing row?
    _mapper.Map(updated, existingFeatureDisa); // copy values from dto to tracked entity.
}
```

No need to call an "Update" method in the repository, all that is left is to await a DbContext.SaveChanges() call and the modified FeatureDisa instances will be persisted. Note that in this option we ***don't*** want to add `AsNoTracking()` to the initial query to get the updateFeatureDisa collection. We want tracked references so that we can let EF do it's thing.

Automapper's documentation around that copy Mapper.Map call has been pretty lacking in the past. It's really useful for update actions like this.

The only other detail you can add to this option is that when setting up the Automapper configuration from your import DTO to FeatureDisa mapping, you configure it to only copy across the values you intend to allow to be changed. Currently you are using the mapper to construct a new FeatureDisa from the DTO, but since we are updating tracked, loaded records, you can be more pessimistic to guard the update to only allow values you intend to update to protect the data from potentially tampered data coming in. This means your update DTO can be streamlined to reflect only the values that can/should change as you no longer need to pass all of the fields needed to construct a complete FeatureDisa record to `Update`.